# SQL select records with unique ID

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with information concerning patients and their diagnostics. Each patient has a unique identifier, given by `NUM_SEQUENCIAL` and can have multiple diagnosis. I have extracted the information from a larger table, with the following query:

```
select DISTINCT 
    (NUM_SEQUENCIAL), COD_DIAGNOSTICO 
FROM 
    PCE_RP.DIAGNOSTICOS_DOENTE 
WHERE 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '153' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1530' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1531' OR
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1532' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1533' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1534' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1536' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1537' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1538' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1539' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1540' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1541';
```

The result was the following TABLE:

```
NUM_SEQUENCIAL | COD_DIAGNOSTICO
2              | 1541
3              | 153
3              | 1533
4              | 1536
4              | 153
```

Question: how to select only unique patient records, with a given `COD_DIAGNOSTICO`? It can be any `COD_DIAGNOSTICO`, I just want to obtain a table like the following, for instance:

```
NUM_SEQUENCIAL | COD_DIAGNOSTICO
2              | 1541
3              | 153
4              | 1536
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you don't care which COD_DIAGNOSTICO gets returned?

Comment: Precisely, it doesn't matter, I just want unique patients in my table, with any COD_DIAGNOSTICO.

Comment: Then just don't put COD_DIAGNOSTICO in your select - `select DISTINCT 
    (NUM_SEQUENCIAL) from ... `

Comment: Yes, but I need the COD_DIAGNOSTICO column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find MAX and MIN both work for this. Max is better because it will never choose empty values.

```
SELECT  
    (NUM_SEQUENCIAL), MAX(COD_DIAGNOSTICO ) COD_DIAGNOSTICO
FROM 
    PCE_RP.DIAGNOSTICOS_DOENTE 
WHERE 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '153' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1530' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1531' OR
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1532' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1533' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1534' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1536' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1537' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1538' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1539' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1540' OR 
    COD_DIAGNOSTICO = '1541'; 

GROUP BY NUM_SEQUENCIAL
```

You should probably use IN () instead of all those ORs. But I left them in for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT NUM_SEQUENCIAL, COD_DIAGNOSTICO
FROM PCE_RP.DIAGNOSTICOS_DOENTE 
GROUP BY NUM_SEQUENCIAL
HAVING COUNT(NUM_SEQUENCIAL) = 1
```